# can Cmake pkg-config module say if the library is static or not

Tags: cmake, static, pkg-config

I have a program, built with cmake, that (optionally) depends on a library (`openwsman`), which itself depends on some libraries (`libcurl`, `libssl`, `libxml-2.0` ...)

```
  pkg_check_modules(winrm openwsman++ openwsman)
  IF (${winrm_FOUND})
    include_directories(${winrm_INCLUDE_DIRS})
    add_definitions(-DHAVE_WINRM=openwsman)
    target_sources(launch PRIVATE src/exec_impl_winrm_openwsman.cpp)
    target_link_libraries(Tests PRIVATE ${winrm_LIBRARIES})
  ENDIF()
```

If the openwsman library provides shared objects, the link runs fine, and the binary depends on libs the libwsman*.so depends on

But if only static libraries is provided, the linker must have access to libs used by the said static libraries (libcurl, libssl, libcrypto, libxml-2.0)

Is there a way, in cmake, to know the libraries provided by ${winrm_LIBRARIES} are the static ones ?

(BTW: openwsman does NOT provide "static" link options in its .pc file, like libcurl does)

Comment: "Is there a way, in cmake, to know the libraries provided by `${winrm_LIBRARIES}` are the static ones ?" - You may check extension of these libraries (On Windows `lib` prefix should be checked instead). For search libraries, CMake normally uses `find_library` command which just searches a file with one of the possible prefix/suffix. If the file is found, only its path is stored. Note, that `_LIBRARIES` suffix implies, that it could be **several** libraries. And each library could have its own static/shared type.

Comment: There are, indeed, multiple libraries in ${winrm_LIBRARIES}